# In Cricket T20 World Cup 2021, why are Bangladesh & SriLanka Demoted to Group A/B with Afghanistan Promoted to Group 2?

Tags: cricket, ranking, cricket-world-cup, qualifying

In general, Bangladesh & Sri Lanka are more-or-less stable/well-known/competent teams, but it seems like they have to qualify from Group A/B to move to higher rounds. By itself, that is fine; but Afghanistan is definitely not a stable/well-known/competent team which already moved up to Group 2.

What are the decisions, events and choices which made this situation?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [Wikipedia article for the tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_ICC_Men%27s_T20_World_Cup#Teams_and_qualification):

> As of 31 December 2018, the top nine ranked ICC Full Members, alongside hosts India, qualified directly for the 2021 tournament. Of those ten teams, the top eight ranked sides qualified for the Super 12s stage of the tournament. Sri Lanka and Bangladesh did not qualify for the Super 12s, instead being placed in the group stage of the competition.

While you may claim that "Afghanistan is definitely not a stable/well-known/competent team", it is [a fact that they had a higher ranking than both Sri Lanka and Bangladesh at the cut off date (31 December 2018)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190131002935/https://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/mens/team-rankings/t20i), which would seem to me to be almost the definition of competence.  As of 6th October 2021, that is still the case, with Afghanistan ranked 8th, ahead of all of West Indies, Sri Lanka, Zimbabwe and Ireland.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but this is mostly a repeat of the facts on which the question is based. Yes, Bangadesh and Sri Lanka did not qualify, but why ? How did World Champions Sri Lanka go below new comers Afghanistan ? I want to know why this happened. I have attempted to answer it ....

Comment: I saw your earlier edit which was fine, but the next edit was changing my question entirely, hence I have reverted that ; I only want to know about the 3 teams mentioned, not all the 12 teams ....

Comment: I think at this point your question is moving from something which is on-topic for this site to something opinion based and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that a combination of many factors helped Afghanistan rise in Cricket.

Here are few factors:

(1) India helped in highlighting the team by organizing matches in India, even going to the extent of coaching and giving a temporary “home-ground” to the Afghanistan team.

[[ https://theprint.in/theprint-essential/the-rise-and-rise-of-afghan-cricket-with-a-little-help-from-india/69256/ ]]

> The Indian support
> India has played its part in the Afghanistan cricket story. In 2015, the BCCI offered the Shaheed Vijay Singh Pathik Sports Complex in Greater Noida as a temporary “home-ground” to the team.
> Afghanistan even “hosted” a three day T20 series against Bangladesh at Dehradun.
> “All teams touring India will play one cricket match against Afghanistan for which arrangements have been made,” BCCI acting secretary Amitabh Choudhary had said last month.
> Former players Lalchand Rajput and Manoj Prabhakar have coached the Afghanistan team, the latter as bowling coach.

(2) Pakistan has helped too.

[[ Same article ]]

> In a sense, the war at home has, ironically, contributed to the rise of Afghan cricket. Forced out of homes, several of the players such as captain Asghar Stanikzai, Mohammad Nabi, and Mohammad Shahzad, honed their skills at refugees camps across the border in Peshawar, Pakistan.

(3) Same article mentions that Afghanistan beat West Indies (in World Cup 2019 qualifiers & in 2016) & Bangladesh (in 2018 T20 series)

This sets the stage to move to the Decline of Bangladesh & Sri Lanka ....

(4) Bangladesh is Depending on the Big-5 and is gradually Declining :

[[ https://www.thedailystar.net/sports/bangladesh-cricket/irreversible-decline-1607683 ]]

> It seemed that these five cricketers -- three batsmen, the country's greatest all-rounder and its best seamer -- would set examples that lesser and younger cricketers could follow in order to continue a tradition of improved performances. That is no longer true.

[[ https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/views/what-happens-to-bangladesh-cricket-after-the-big-five-1627017692 ]]

> The currently 9th ranked team in ICC Ranking for ODIs, Sri Lanka sets an example of how unexpectedly a world-class team’s performance can decline after the retirement of some great cricketers of the nation.
> Whether Bangladesh has to go back to where they were in the early 2000s or not after the retirement of the ‘big five’ depends on the future prospects and how they are utilised.

(5) Sri Lanka is gradually Declining over the Political Interference & the Infighting between Players & Management & the Financial crisis.

[[ https://www.tbsnews.net/sports/inevitable-fall-sri-lankan-cricket-what-actually-happened-252751 ]]

> Political interference has been pretty acute cricket in Sri Lanka for quite some time now. And it is ruining their game
> ....
> The most anyone has heard about Sri Lankan cricket in the last few days is probably about the **dispute between the players and the board** on players' huge pay cut and the unrest that followed. Well, they have also lost the ODI series to Bangladesh, for the first time in their history. ....  And they are currently at the bottom of the ODI Super League and **at risk of not qualifying directly** for the upcoming 2023 cricket world cup.
> ....
> Just to remind, Sri Lanka won the CWC in 1996 and played in two consecutive finals in 2007 and 2011. They were the champions of the T20 WC in 2014. But all those feel like distant memories now.
> ....
> Financial crisis definitely played a big part in the fall.

(6) Sri Lanka is gradually Declining over Retirement Of Key Players.

[[ https://www.probatsman.com/three-reasons-behind-the-decline-of-sri-lankan-cricket ]]

> With such a great composition already serving the country, the inclusion of any youngster looked very hard at that time. This is where Sri Lanka did not plan much for a future and relied heavily upon the existing players who were match-winners for them and that is what cost them.

This covers why Afghanistan has moved Up while Bangladesh & Sri Lanka have moved Down ....